# weak-* topologies

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Say $S = \{z \in \ell_\infty : z_n \in \{0,1\}\}$. Suppose I am asked a question about the weak-* topology on $S$. How am I supposed to make sense of this? The weak-* topology is a topology on a dual of a space. So ... should I find a space $X$ such that $X^* = S$ for this case? It seems I would need to find $X$ anyway in order to know the weak generators of the weak-* topology (the image of $X$ in $X^{**}$).

Also, how would I even find $X$ in this case?

EDIT: Ohh, am I supposed to just look at $S$ as a (topological) subspace of $\ell_\infty$ with the weak-* topology on $\ell_\infty$ (because I can deal with that).

Comment: The idea is the $\ell_1^{\ast} = \ell_{\infty}$

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan: Right, but $S$ isn't even a vector subspace here, so am I just supposed to consider $S$ as a topological subspace of $\ell_\infty$ (because I know what the weak-* topology on $\ell_\infty$ is)?

Comment: Yes, $S$ is just a topological space in this problem, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments by Prahlad Vaidyanathan:

1. $\ell_\infty$ is equipped with weak* topology, being the dual of $\ell_1$
2. Every subset of $\ell_\infty$ also gets (a piece of) weak* topology, by restriction.

*Tangential remark.* The above naturally raises the question of consistency: what if the subset $S$ happens to be a closed linear subspace of $\ell_\infty$? Is the restriction of weak* topology also a weak* topology in this case? The answer is yes: $S$ is naturally identified with the dual of $\ell_1/({}^\perp S)$, where the awkward notation $({}^\perp S)$ means the *pre-annihilator* of $S$, namely $$({}^\perp S)=\{x\in \ell_1 : \phi(x)=0 \quad \forall \phi \in S\}$$